# Excel VBA validar string de una variable como un campo de texto de un formulario

Tags: excel, vba, variables

En un escenario normal, cuando quiero guardar un valor que un usuario ingresó en un formulario uso la siguiente sentencia:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SALIDAS").Range("B" & fila) = UCase(Me.descripcion.Value)
```

En donde a partir del valor Me.descripcion.Value el sistema ubica el textBox "descripcion" y registra el valor de dicho textbox, esto funciona bien si conozco exactamente el nombre del campo del formulario.

Ahora bien, mi problemática está en que tengo una variable que representa el nombre del campo que necesito ingresar.

```
Dim descripcion As String
descripcion = "Me.descripcion_0.value"
```

Pero el sistema no evalúa esta variable como un campo del formulario sino como un string, entonces si intento emplear la variable para hacer un guardado en el sistema:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SALIDAS").Range("E" & fila) = descripcion
```

lo que consigo es guardar literalmente el string "Me.descripción_0.value" y no el valor que el usuario ingresó en el formulario.

Como puedo conseguir que el sistema evalúe el string al momento de guardar el registro de tal manera que no guarde literalmente el string, sino que interprete este como un campo del formulario y obtenga su valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya logré realizar la operación, por lo que dejo el escenario aquí.

En primer lugar mi variable no debería contener todo el string sino únicamente el nombre del textBox en el input... Es decir. No debería Tener el valor

```
Dim descripcion As String
descripcion = "Me.descripcion_0.value"
```

Sino que debería tener el valor:

```
Dim descripcion As String
descripcion = "descripcion_0"
```

De esta manera, para realizar el registro se utiliza el objeto "Controls" del formulario pasandole el nombre del input para obtener el valor:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SALIDAS").Range("E" & fila) = nombreFormulario.Controls(descripcion).Value
```

Y de esta manera el sistema si obtiene el valor correcto del textbox del formulario y no el string de la variable.

Comment: Muy bien! Bien explicado y encontraste la respuesta a tu propia pregunta! Por favor márca la respuesta como aceptada, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 1):

Solo hay que quitar las comillas.

Tu código esta así:

```
descripcion = "Me.descripcion_0.value"
```

Cámbialo a esto:

```
descripcion = Me.descripcion_0.value
```